# How to solve Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined in Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, datatable

```
<?php
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {?>
        <table class="table table-striped" id="example" align="center">
            <tr>
                <thead>
                    <th style="padding:7px">Name</th>
                    <th style="padding:7px">Email</th>
                    <th style="padding:7px">Position</th>
                    <th style="padding:7px">Action</th>
                </thead>
            </tr>
                <tbody id="myTable">
    <?php
        echo "<tr>";
        
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            echo "<td style='padding:7px'>".$row["name"]."</td>";
            echo "<td style='padding:7px'>".$row["email"]."</td>";
            echo "<td style='padding:7px'>".$row["position"]."</td>";
            ?>
            <td style='padding:7px'><button class="btn btn-info"  onclick="deleteUser('<?php echo $row['id'];?>')"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> DELETE </button> |
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="edit_user.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> EDIT</a> |       
            <button class="btn btn-info  abc" value="View Data" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> VIEW DATA </button>
    
            </td>
    
    
            <?php echo "</tr>"; 
        } ?>
                </tbody>
    
                <tfoot>
                <th style="padding:7px">Name</th>
                <th style="padding:7px">Email</th>
                <th style="padding:7px">Position</th>
                <th style="padding:7px">Action</th>
                </tfoot>
                
        <?php
         echo "</table>";
         
     }
    else
        {
            echo "No row exists";
        }
    ?>
```

I am using Jquery Datatable for sorting,searching and paging data. after i run the code it shown an error _DT_CellIndex' of undefined.
`<tr>`, `<td>`, `<th>`,`<thead>`,`<tbody>`,`<tfoot>` tags are used properly and closed properly.
Help me out to solve this problem.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL6Is.jpg

Comment: There is no _DT_CellIndex in this code, so the issue is not here. Can you provide the full error message and the code it references?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
    at Ka (jquery.dataTables.min.js:37)
    at R (jquery.dataTables.min.js:29)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:30)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at Function.map (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.map (jquery.min.js:2)
    at oa (jquery.dataTables.min.js:30)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:106)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:107)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)   aynber

Comment: Might be helpful to show the compiled HTML output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I googled your error and looks like that generally means that your table is malformed in some way, like having mismatched row sizes.

I then messed around by putting your table in this HTML Table Validator:

https://wet-boew.github.io/wet-boew-legacy/v3.1/demos/tableparser/validator-htmltable.html

And it said "Error: You can not define any row before the thead group"

I'm pretty sure your problem is that you need to nest the `tr` inside of `thead`, instead of the other way around:

```
        <table class="table table-striped" id="example" align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th style="padding:7px">Name</th>
                    <th style="padding:7px">Email</th>
                    <th style="padding:7px">Position</th>
                    <th style="padding:7px">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

Comment: jaypb Thanks for solving this. this is working perfectly now.